# Table with only tbody scrollable (without left th column)

Tags: html, css

I have a table with both top row and left column as sticky header, structured like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1</th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>content</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>content</td>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The question is: how can I make scrollbar shown only inside td area? Not on the left column, not on the header row.
In order for scrollbar not to be shown outside the table body I removed overflow:scroll from the parent of the table, but in this case table just starts to get all the space it needs (so it overgrows it's parent) so there is nothing to scroll, so I was not able to see if 'overflow: scroll' on tbody works at least for the header.

Thanks in advance! So stucked here.

Comment: Could you please provide your CSS?

Comment: Sure! Here I created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-monad-ookef?file=/styles.css

Comment: I see you have a sticky row and a sticky column. It's not very clear what the problem is. The table scrolls normally.

Comment: I have a requirement for a scrollbar to work and to move only inside the table content, while now it appears on the whole table

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify width and height of the `container`:

```css
thead tbody {
    display: block;
}
#sheet-table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
#root-cell {
    background-color: grey;
    z-index: 3;
}
#root-cell :before {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.cell {
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.column-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.row-header {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.row-header, .column-header {
    color: black;
    background-color: grey;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table id="sheet-table">
      <thead>
        <tr id="row-header header">
          <th id="root-cell" class="cell row-header column-header"></th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 1 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 2 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 3 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 4 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 5 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 6 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 7 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 8 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 9 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 10 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 11 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 12 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 13 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 14 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 15 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 16 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 17 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 18 </th>
          <th class="column-header cell"> 19 </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">1</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">2</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">3</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">4</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">5</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">6</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">7</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">8</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">9</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header cell">10</th>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
          <td class="cell"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```